# How to get /:id on route POST?

Tags: node.js, express

https://github.com/AEkman/Quiz/blob/master/app.js

I'm trying to get the /:id and save it to a variable called quizId. I'm using this link to make a route POST:

- http://localhost:3000/takequiz/2

This is my POST function

```
app.post('/takequiz/:id', function(req, res) {
    var quizId = req.body.id;
    console.log(quizId);
```

Why am I only getting

> 'undefined'

as answer? This works when I'm using GET instead? I've tried params and query aswell but no luck.

Comment: You possibly lack the body parsing middleware in the pipeline.

Comment: it definitely shouldn't be in the body, you passed it in the url which of course isn't the body. It should be in params.

Comment: Be careful with express-bodyparser as it exposes your app to some security flaws

Comment: Well, since not everyone on the project understood the routing system we put everything in app.js so something might have happend on the way. This is a beginner project and just for show. I added the github link aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's not part of the body, but part of the url.

Try `req.params.id` instead of `req.body.id`, and everything should be fine.

Comment: Accessing a url parameter in Express *does work* using `req.params.whatever`. So if this did not work, the error must be somewhere else, but using `req.params.id` is correct, while using `req.body.id` is not. And from the code snippet that the OP has shown, it *has* to be `req.params.id` and then it *will* work.

Comment: Right, but if the user tried .params and it didn't work, does this answer the question?

Comment: With respect to what he submitted as part of the question, yes. Because this is the only thing wrong in his code. It may be that there is another problem, but it's not part of the code he has shown us. In that sense, yes, it answers the question.

Comment: I have to disagree. that fact simply makes the question unclear and unanswerable.

Comment: Fine. Apart from pointing out that my answer (that points out an obvious error in his code) does not help, do you have anything else which might be constructive?

Comment: The method used is `post`, the param extraction is equivalent to the body-parser method of a post param. For his snippet, the URL param `:id` is effectively irrelevant. The issue at hand is OP cannot grab the posted value, and changing the method to GET does not solve anything here

Comment: I think there must be something else wrong because it has worked my req.params.id before.

We are 4 people working on this project so maybe someone has made a change somewhere that they weren't supposed to.

I added the git file

Comment: Nobody suggested to change the method to `GET`.

Comment: Golo gets the gold

Answer (score -1):

Hi use ajax with jquery to send data to the post function of api rest.

```
// data
var takequiz1={id:4, message:"Hello Word"};

// Use AJAX to post the object

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: takequiz1,
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/takequiz/',
        dataType: 'JSON'
    }).done(function( response ) {

    });

//POST FUNCTION API NODE JS
router.post('/takequiz',function(req,res,next){
       var id= req.body.id;
       var message = req.body.message;
});
```

Comment: That won't help me. I want to get the /:id of the current route and send that ID with an INSERT query to mysql along with some other variables.